# Moment Date passing as valid when it isnt

Tags: momentjs

The value is true, can anyone please tell me why this is?

```
var testValue = "25 merits";

var testDate = momentLib(testValue, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss').isValid(); // true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser tries to automatically fix errors and is in general very "forgiving" with the input it gets.

Starting with version 2.3.0, you can specify another parameter to tell the parser to be strict about the input and reject anything which doesn't match exactly what is expected, like this:

```
var testValue = "25 merits";

var testDate = momentLib(testValue, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss', true).isValid(); // false
```

See docs: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/